# Get column of a matrix python with index operator

Tags: python, matrix, overloading

How can I refactor this code to generalize the argument parsing? I feel like this code can be better but I can't find a way. The usage syntax of the index operator is similar to the NumPy indexing syntax.

```
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
    """
    [] operator to index elements in the matrix
    Usage: 
    >> mat[0] returns first row
    >> mat[3, :] return the 4th row
    >> mat[:, 7] return the 8th column
    >> mat[0, 0] returns first element
    """
    if isinstance(arg, int):
        return self.matrix[arg]
    elif isinstance(arg, tuple):
        if isinstance(arg[0], int) and isinstance(arg[1], int):
            y, x = arg
            return self.matrix[x][y]
        elif isinstance(arg[0], slice) and isinstance(arg[1], int):
            return self.get_column(arg[1])
        elif isinstance(arg[0], int) and isinstance(arg[1], slice):
            return self.get_column(arg[1])
    else :
        raise TypeError('Invalid indexing arguments type', arg)
```

Also, how can I make a setitem function that uses the [] operator to set columns without rewriting the getitem function inside it? Here is my current implementation without the possibility of setting a column.

```
    def __setitem__(self, arg, value):
    if isinstance(value, Fraction):
        self[arg] = value
    elif isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(elem, Fraction) for elem in value):
        self[arg] = value
    else:
        raise TypeError('Invalid value type', value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before improving the code it would be worth fixing the following problems.

1. The docstring says:

   ```
   >> mat[3, :] return the 4th row
   ```

   but the implementation tries to return a column:

   ```
   elif isinstance(arg[0], int) and isinstance(arg[1], slice):
       return self.get_column(arg[1])
   ```

   but since `arg[1]` is a slice object, this will fail in some way. (I can't say exactly how since you didn't show us the code for `get_column`.)
2. The indexing is inconsistent. As it says in the docstring:

   ```
   >> mat[3, :] return the 4th row
   ```

   but to get the first element of the fourth row, you have to write:

   ```
   mat[0, 3]
   ```

   because the indexes get swapped:

   ```
   y, x = arg
   return self.matrix[x][y]
   ```

   This is contrary to the way indexing works in NumPy and so seems very likely to lead to confusion.
3. If you pass a tuple of length 1 then this causes an `IndexError`:

   ```
   >>> mat[:,]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "cr189408.py", line 21, in __getitem__
       elif isinstance(arg[0], slice) and isinstance(arg[1], int):
   IndexError: tuple index out of range
   ```
4. If you pass a pair of slices then this is ignored and `__getitem__` returns `None`.

   ```
   >>> mat[:,:] is None
   True
   ```

   In NumPy this would return the whole matrix.
5. The code only checks whether the argument is a slice or not, and if it is a slice, it assumes that the whole row or column is required. This is right if a bare `:` was passed, but misleading if some other slice was passed. In NumPy `mat[0:2, 0]` gets the *first two* element of column 0, but the code in the post returns the *whole* of column 0.